# Interpret python code within python program

Tags: python, pip, pythoninterpreter

Is there a library for interpreting python code within a python program?
Sample usage might look like this..

```
code = """
def hello():
    return 'hello'

hello()
"""

output = Interpreter.run(code)
print(output)
```

which then outputs
`hello`

Comment: You can use `exec`, take a look at the code below, I've updated my answer. You can't get the return value from that code. Instead you can print it there itself.

Comment: My example code "requires" a return statement that I can store in `output` though, so its not the solution that I'm looking for. Thanks for the response anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found this example from grepper

```
the_code = '''
a = 1
b = 2
return_me = a + b
'''

loc = {}
exec(the_code, globals(), loc)
return_workaround = loc['return_me']
print(return_workaround)
```

apparently you can pass global and local scope into `exec`. In your use case, you would just use a named variable instead of returning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` function. You can't get the return value from the code variable. Instead you can print it there itself.

```
code = """
def hello():
    print('hello')
hello()
"""

exec(code)
```